# Can't open file to disable splash screen

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, screen, plymouth, gksu

I'm on Xubuntu 15.04 32 bit if that means anything. It's a fresh install. I'm trying to disable the splash screen. (There actually doesn't seem to be any. It's a black screen from boot until I get to the login screen) 
I type in

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

the terminal. It asks for a password, I type it and press "ok" After that nothing happens. I try the same command with root access and I get:

```
(gksu:3166): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to disable the splash screen, use the standard command line text editor for Ubuntu:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Make your changes and update the Grub config

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Is there any reason I wasn't able to use gksu gedit though?

Comment: This should be a new question :)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)